Is it possible to double click a .glb file in windows and have it open in Blender?
I am a game developer and when I'm working, I go in and out of hundreds of different .glb files (sometimes .obj, sometimes .fbx) and it is very tedious to go through the import/export process every time. It would save me a lot of time if I could double click to open a .glb file, then press ctrl-s to overwrite that same .glb file. I am just wondering if there is an addon or something I'm missing that can give me this behavior. Thank you in advance.

I hope someone answers your question better than I but maybe if you asked Chat GPT for exactly what you need, you could get a python code and paste it in Blender and run it, fingers crossed, maybe you might get what you want.
Also with a code in hand you could ask again about it on another post in case it doesn't work.

Opening and saving .fbx or .obj files is not yet implemented in Blender, but there is an add-on that may help you:
Quick exporter

This addon does the job for you  https://github.com/mika-f/blender-drag-and-drop
And it works with the most recent versions of Blender. It is not click to open Blender but drag & drop works just fine
